# Why doesn't FullSimplify simplify expressions with DiracDelta?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, distributions

I want to simplify a complicated expression with some Dirac delta distributions, but FullSimplify does not do what I want. Specifically, I want

```
FullSimplify[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], x>0 && y>0]
```

to evaluate to `DiracDelta[x - y]`. Does anybody know how to make Mathematica simplify this?

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: may be because it does not know if x>y? `Assuming[x > 0 && y > 0 && x > y, FullSimplify[x/y DiracDelta[x - y]]]` gives zero.  (I assume you are looking for zero as answer.) The point is, just telling M that `x>0` and `y>0`, does not say anything about if `x==y` or not.

Comment: I am looking for `DiracDelta[x-y]` as an answer. I added the assumptions only to avoid a division by zero, so the constraint on `x` is not needed. From the answer @Jens gave below, we can see that even that constraint is not necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a trick that allows you to get exactly what you're looking for:

```
FourierTransform[
 InverseFourierTransform[
   x/y DiracDelta[x - y], 
 x, k],
k, x]
```

> `DiracDelta[x - y]`

What I did here is to apply the Fourier transform and its inverse, which is of course the identity and therefore is equivalent to the original expression. But in doing so, *Mathematica* automatically did the required simplifications because it knows exactly how to deal with Dirac deltas inside Fourier integrals. By the way, *Mathematica* can even deal with *derivatives* of the delta function in the same way.

**Edit**

As stated by Nikki in the comment, it's important to keep track of which entry in the `DiracDelta` is the intended integration variable. This is not always clear from just looking at the delta function because it is by definition symmetric. The choice of intended integration variable is specified in the `InverseFourierTransform` above.

**The reason why it's not done by `Simplify`**

The ambiguity as to the integration variable is really the answer to the question **why** `FullSimplify` doesn't do anything with `DiracDelta`. Strictly speaking, `DiracDelta` is a **distribution** and not a function. It picks out the value of a function given to it, at the position specified by a parameter. This operation happens to be symmetric *in the example of the question* in that parameter and function variable have interchangeable roles, but nonetheless their distinction becomes important when the argument of `DiracDelta` is itself a function that depends on the "parameter" and the "variable" in an asymmetric way.

Take, for example, $y\,\delta(x-f(y))$. If we assume $x$ to be the integration variable, nothing needs to be simplified. If, on the other hand, $y$ is the integration variable, the simplification goal would be to let $y$ stand alone inside the delta function, requiring us to invert the function $f$. There is no way to decide which of these routes is desired unless you *state* whether $x$ or $y$ is the integration variable. This situation is illustrated in the examples below.

**More examples**

Sometimes you do have to add assumptions in order to get a fully simplified result, because *Mathematica*'s default assumption that variables are *complex*  also applies to `DiracDelta`, and you may not want that. Here is an example, modified from the comment by Dr.Wolfgang:

```
Assuming[y > 0, 
 FourierTransform[
  InverseFourierTransform[
    (y/x DiracDelta[y - x^2]),
   x, k], k, x]]
```

> `1/2 DiracDelta[x - Sqrt[y]] - 1/2 DiracDelta[x + Sqrt[y]]`

This is an application of the transformation of variables formula for delta functions. We can push this to make even more symbolically general statements like this:

```
Assuming[y > 0 && n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
 FourierTransform[
  InverseFourierTransform[
    (y/x DiracDelta[y - x^n]),
   x, k], k, x]]
```

> `DiracDelta[x - y^(1/n)]/n`

However, as you can see by comparison with the previous, more concrete result (`n = 2`), the more general answer here is missing the fact that the inverse of the power has multiple branches which should be summed over. So I guess this is a *caveat* not to get carried away and always do a sanity check when simplifying complicated delta function expressions with *Mathematica*.

Comment: For completeness it is useful to note that the order of using the functions is immaterial. `InverseFourierTransform[
 FourierTransform[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], x, k], k, x]` gives the same result.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, that's right, either way is fine (and if for some reason one way doesn't work, you can always try the other order to make sure).

Comment: I was hoping for something more general than this trick, but it works if you know which variables occur in the Dirac delta. If nobody comes with a more elegant solution I will accept your answer in a day.

Comment: @ Jens: nice trick. But look what happens if you do it with  (x/y DiracDelta[x - y^2]).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Well, you get the correct answer. There is no problem at all.  @Nikki Yes, the notation of the Dirac delta function is sometimes ambiguous because it doesn't include the info as to which variable is the integration variable. This can only be fixed by stating that information in the (`Inverse`)`FourierTransform`.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I did find a shortcoming when I switched the variables in your example and replaced the square by a symbolic `n` - see my edit. But I think one gets pretty decent results all in all.

Comment: @ Jens: no, I don't. In V8 the trick for (x/y DiracDelta[x - y^2]) does NOT simplify to y DiracDelta[x - y^2]. What is your result?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Ah, so this time it was good that I used version 10.0.1. There, it does simplify exactly to what you quoted...thanks for pointing out the issue with 8!

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I just checked in version 8.0.4, and I cannot reproduce your problem. It simplifies correctly on my system, even in the older version. This is on Mac OS 10.7.5.

Comment: @NikkiBisschop I edited my answer to include more examples, and what I say in the first paragraph of the edit is based on your comment. It is in fact the answer to your overarching question *why* `DiracDelta` isn't simplified as such. One *needs* the information identifying the integration variable to make the correct simplification.

Comment: @Jens and @Dr.WolfgangHintze, thanks for all the additions. I do not have any functions in my delta function fortunately, I meant that I have `DiracDelta[a-b]` sometimes and I was hoping that there was a way to simplify this without stating that `a` or `b` were variables, but it seems that there isn't. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Simplifying a routine algebraic expression by Fourier transforming is quite extravagant. Developers should take note and improve the Generalized function modules.

Answer (score 2):

`DiracDelta` must be inside an integral to have much meaning. From its documentation: "`DiracDelta` can be used in integrals, integral transforms, and differential equations. "

```
Assuming[Element[y, Reals],
 Integrate[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

> 1

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals],
 Integrate[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

> 1

```
Assuming[x > y,
 Integrate[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

> 0

```
Assuming[y > x,
 Integrate[x/y DiracDelta[x - y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

> 0