# Verifying $x(t)\delta(t)=x(0)\delta(t)$ in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

How can I verify the property $x(t)\delta(t)=x(0)\delta(t)$ in Mathematica? I tried with:

```
In[5]:= x[t_] := t

In[6]:= x[t] DiracDelta[t] == x[0] DiracDelta[t]

Out[6]= t DiracDelta[t] == 0
```

I expect the output True.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ar you sure you weren't thinking about $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\mathrm dx=f(0)$$?

Comment: Hi @J.M. see (3) http://www.physicspages.com/2011/02/16/dirac-delta-function/ please.

Comment: The above property is also at page 81 on book Bracewell - The Fourier Transform And Its Applications.

Comment: As a generalized function, `DiracDelta` is defined in the context of an integral. Integrate both sides: `Integrate[x[t] DiracDelta[t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 
 Integrate[x[0] DiracDelta[t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: Closely related: [Why doesn't FullSimplify simplify expressions with DiracDelta?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63695/245)

Comment: Usually, equations involved with Dirac delta function are meaningful after integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted by Bob Hanlon in the comments, $\delta(t)$ is not defined outside of integrals, so it doesn't make any sense to ask the question whether $x(t)\delta(t)=x(0)\delta(t)$.

However, what you can do is verify that both expressions behave the same under the integral, i.e. that $\int f(t) g(t)\mathrm{d}t$ is the same for $f(t)=x(t)\delta(t)$ and $f(t)=x(0)\delta(t)$:

```
In[1]:=  Integrate[x[t] DiracDelta[t] f[t], t] == Integrate[x[0] DiracDelta[t] f[t], t]
Out[1]:= True
```

Here, you don't need to define anything for `x[t]`, as this is true for all `x[t]`.

#### Update 2

As noted in the comments, we should only consider definite integrals. This leads to the following definition of `GeneralizedEqual`:

```
GeneralizedEqual[f_, g_, t_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Integrate[h[t] f, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, opts]
  == Integrate[h[t] g, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, opts]
```

With this definition, we can also prove the generalized version of the original equation (again, see comments), $\delta(t-T)x(t)"="\delta(t-T)x(T)$:

```
In[1]:= GeneralizedEqual[DiracDelta[t - T] f[t], DiracDelta[t - T] f[T], t]
Out[1]= ConditionalExpression[True, T \[Element] Reals]
```

#### Update

To make it a bit nicer to look at, you can introduce a generalized version of `==`:

```
In[1]:=  GeneralizedEqual[f_, g_, t_] := Integrate[h[t] f, t] == Integrate[h[t] g, t]
In[2]:=  GeneralizedEqual[x[t] DiracDelta[t], x[0] DiracDelta[t], t]
Out[2]:= True
```

Comment: Hi @Mathe172. I tried to prove Integrate[DiracDelta[t - T] f[t], t] == 
 Integrate[DiracDelta[t - T] f[T], t], but the output is not True. Can you tell me I get True please?

Comment: Your definition of `GeneralizedEqual` is not quite right, since the generalized functions are only defined via definite integrals.  So this would be a better one: `GeneralizedEqual[f_, g_, t_,opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Integrate[h[t] f,  {t,-Infinity,Infinity},opts] == Integrate[h[t] g, {t,-Infinity,Infinity},opts]`

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi See my comment my previous comment.  If you used the GeneralizedEqual from there, you will find that `GeneralizedEqual[DiracDelta[t - T] f[t], DiracDelta[t - T] f[T], t]` returns `ConditionalExpression[True, T \[Element] Reals]`, and indeed the result is only valid if T is a real number.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Thanks for pointing that out - I updated the answer to incorporate your improvements

Answer (score 3):

You get it directly with [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html):

```
 In[1]:= FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[t]*f[t]]

 Out[1]= DiracDelta[t] f[0]

 In[2]:= FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[t-5]*f[t]]

 Out[2]= DiracDelta[-5+t] f[5]

 In[3]:= FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[t+2]*f[t]]

 Out[3]= DiracDelta[2+t] f[-2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.  Executing `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ExportMultipleCellsOptions -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]` will keep the `In[]`/`Out[]` labels from being pasted.  That makes it easier for others to copy and test code.