# Simplifying polynomial fractions with same `DiracDelta` function in both denominator and numerator

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions, complex

I am trying to simplify an expression with multiple Diracdelta functions in both numerator and denominator. For example,

```
expr = (x1 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]+x2 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω])/
        (x3 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω] - x4 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]) // FullSimplify
```

However, `DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]` does not cancel out during the simplification.
I have already read answers to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187616/fullsimplify-with-two-diracdelta-functions), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/verifying-xt-deltat-x0-deltat-in-mathematica?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63695/why-doesnt-fullsimplify-simplify-expressions-with-diracdelta) questions, and I understand that this is due to the definition of `DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]`.

This is my approach:

```
expr /.{DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]->X}// FullSimplify
```

[image]

It works, however, not very convenient for complicated expressions with multiple `DiracDelta` at different values.

Is there any better approach to cancel out same `DiracDelta` functions both denominator and numerator?

Comment: There are problems with multiplication of distributions (see the Problem of multiplication section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) ). Division is multiplication by inverse distribution.

Comment: Got it. But here, I just want to use Mathematica to analyse an electrical circuit and I want similar terms to be cancelled out.

Comment: It is impossible to simplify an indeterminate expression. Here is a simpler example FullSimplify[1/Gamma[n - 1]/Gamma[n], 
 Assumptions -> n \ [Element] Integers] . The expression in your question is indeterminate because the supports of the numerator and denominator are the same. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Here is a similar command to yours FullSimplify[(2*0 - 0)/(5*0 - 3*0)] which is answered Indeterminate.

Comment: @user64494, well, it depends on the context. Here, I am analysing an electrical circuit and I want to extract its characteristics at a particular frequency. My question here is not about matth, but the use of Mathematica for my purpose.

Comment: Use `//Factor` instead of `//FullSimplify`

Comment: @BillWatts, Perfect! If you could add this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer instead of comment.

Use `//Factor` instead of `//FullSimplify`

Comment: All that is built on the sand because the expression under simplification is indeterminate. You demonstrate rather a weakness of Mathematica than its capacities.

Comment: The Factor command is so powerful: even Factor[(3*"0" - "0")/(2*"0" - "0")] performs 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = (x1 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω] + x2 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω])/(x3 DiracDelta[ω0 + \
ω] - x4 DiracDelta[ω0 + ω]) // Cancel

(* (x1 + x2)/(x3 - x4)  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: All that is built on the sand because the expression under simplification is indeterminate. You demonstrate rather a weakness of Mathematica than its capacities.

Comment: @user64494  No. One should understand delta-function as a limit of a bell-shaped function. In that case one makes simplification and passes to the limit.

Comment: This is the limit in the weak topology (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function for info). Mathematica does not deal with such limits.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, Thanks, this also works! I accepted the other answer because he first put it as a comment.

Comment: The Cancel command is so powerful: even Cancel[(3*"0" - "0")/(2*"0" - "0")] performs 2.