# Fullsimplify with two Diracdelta functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am having a problem with the FullSimplify and DiracDelta functions. When I run the following line in mathmatica:

```
Assuming[x >= 0 && y > 1, FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x]*DiracDelta[x - y]]]
```

the results is:

> DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y]

while I expect 0. Any clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your understanding of the DiracDelta command is not true: DiracDelta is a distribution, not a usual function. In particular, DiracDelta[2] makes no sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading.

Comment: This reply is totally confusing. No matter how you interpret the dirac function, the mathmatical equality above is correct.

Comment: As another point, if you change the x-y to x+y mathmatica correctly evaluates the expression to zero. I really think an assumption is missing or mathmatica has got a bug.

Comment: Arguments are over nongrounded words.

Comment: See discussions in the answer bellow.

Comment: A reason one might think that *M* would do what the OP seeks is this: `Assuming[x > 0, FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x]]]`.  But in the more complicated case in the question, `FullSimplify` does not seem to work out the relationship between the two delta functions.

Comment: @Michael E2: Unfortunately, the result of the simplification Assuming[x>0,FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x]]] makes no sense in traditional math.

Comment: @user64494 But we're in *Mathematica*, not mathematics.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean Assuming[x>0,FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x]]] =0 does not make sense in traditional math? This is totally valid. Can you explain more?

Comment: @AJ. : Did you read the linked Wiki article? I quote for your convenience "  It is used to model the density of an idealized point mass or point charge as a function equal to zero everywhere except for zero and whose integral over the entire real line is equal to one.[1][2][3] As there is no function that has these properties, the computations made by the theoretical physicists appeared to mathematicians as nonsense until the introduction of distributions by Laurent Schwartz to formalize and validate the computations".

Comment: @user64494 The result $\delta(x)=0$ for $x>0$ makes perfect sense. It means that $\delta[f]=0$ for all $f$ whose support is $x>0$. Just because *you* don't understand a concept does not mean that the concept itself makes no sense. **Please stop making comments on every post that contain the words "Dirac delta", especially wrong comments**.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Can you kindly give us a reference to base your claim  " It means that $\delta[f]=0$ for all $f$ whose support is $x>0$ "? AFAII, the support of  any test function should be a compact.

Comment: Micael E2: Do you mean that Mathematica math differs from traditional math?

Comment: @user64494 No, the support need not be compact (recall that $\delta$ is tempered). A Schwartz function is a smooth function such that $|P\partial_\alpha f|<\infty$  for all multi-indices $\alpha$ and all polynomials $P$. For example, a gaussian function is Schwartz, and its support is all of $\mathbb R$. Moreover, $\mathrm{sup}(f)\subset \{x>0\}$ does not mean that the support is not compact. For example, $\mathrm{sup}(f)=[1,2]$ is both compact and in $x>0$. These are traditional results; any reference should do.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Can you give a reference to  your claim  " It means that $\delta[f]=0$ for all $f $ whose support is $x>0$ " Up to Wiki, "A typical space of test functions consists of all smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support that have as many derivatives as required".

Comment: @user64494 A "typical space of test functions" is not the only possibility. Note that I said *tempered*. If you don't know basic distribution theory, don't post comments trying to correct others. It is obnoxious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86841/discussion-between-user64494-and-accidentalfouriertransform).

Answer (score 1):

Within Mathematica, `DiracDelta` makes only sense within `Integrate` (or integral transforms such as `FourierTransform`. And a product of `DiracDelta` makes only sense in a multidimensional setting:

```
Assuming[x >= 0 && y > 1,
 Integrate[DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
 ]
```

returns

[image]

If one uses two-dimensional integration and incorporates the assumptions into the integration, one obtains the desired results:

```
Integrate[ DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] f[x, y], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 1, ∞}]
Integrate[ DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x + y] f[x, y], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 1, ∞}]
```

> 0
>
> 0

---

By the way, Mathematica seem to interpret functions in the integrant as functions that are *compactly support in the interior* of the integration domain:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] f[x, y], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] f[x, y], {x, -ϵ, ∞}, {y, -ϵ, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> ϵ > 0]
```

This can lead to wrong results when integration function that do not vanish on the domain of integration:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] Cos[x + y], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[x - y] Cos[x + y], {x, -ϵ, ∞}, {y, -ϵ, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> ϵ > 0]
```

> 0
>
> 1

Here, I would have expected that both evaluate to `1`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence. Surely $x=2=y$ satisfies $x=y$ and $x\ge0$ and $y>0$. Is there a typo somewhere? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are not making a mistake with the limits of the integral? With the correct limits these integrals will both evaluate to zero.

Comment: Well of course one of the delta functions diverges for x=y=2, but the point is that the other delta function is zero already.

Comment: The answer to the following question might be relevant, but it is just a trick, that makes the whole simplification more complicated.
[link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63695/why-doesnt-fullsimplify-simplify-expressions-with-diracdelta)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Uh. Good point. Now I get what A.J. meant.

Comment: Yepp........ =D

Comment: @A.J. Sorry, I got some of your remarks wrong. Please have a look at my newest edit.